# How to proxy custom domains to vuejs app?

Tags: vue.js, nginx, vue-router, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to proxy multiple domains to my vuejs app.

I have a VueJS application, with the following route: `https://app.pingr.io/status/{id}`.

What I want to do is to allow users to redirect their domains to this route. So, imagine we have a https://status.some-domain.com host, which is redirected using CNAME to `https://app.pingr.io/status/status.some-domain.com`.

I really can't figure out the nginx configuration for this.

What I have right now:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        #resolver 127.0.0.1 [::1];
        #resolver 8.8.8.8;

        proxy_pass https://app.pingr.io/status/test/;
    }

    location /js/ {
        proxy_pass https://app.pingr.io/js/;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    }

    location /css/ {
        proxy_pass https://app.pingr.io/css/;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    }
}
```

Before passing $host variable to proxy_pass at first I'm trying to just proxy to /status/test with working js/css/images.

I managed to get js/css work, however instead of getting the content of /status/test route, I get redirected to the home page. I displayed routes in `router.beforeEach`, so I can see that the first route I'm being redirected to is home route.

I was trying different configurations, like including proxy_set_header host and other stuff, which actually broke the whole thing even more.

So what is the right way to do this? Once again, users should be able to redirect their domains to my vuejs route and pass their domain to a part of this route. The domain should be rewritten, so that it looks like the page belongs to their server/domain.

Comment: Hello Victor, I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you talking about HTTP redirects (that change the page URL in your users' browsers) or about DNS CNAMEs that are basically aliases to other domains?

Comment: User setups cname in his DNS records which points to my domain. Like, imagine there is a cname record CNAME custom-domain.com status.pingr.io. What need is when user goes to custom-domain.com it behaves like he goes to app.pingr.io/status/custom-domain.com. Then I can handle the rest